# multiple annotations found at this line in pom.xml

Tags: maven

Multiple annotations found at this line in pom.xml after adding below dependency to the pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

i wanted to write some test case for my spring boot application. I just tried adding "spring-boot-starter-test" artifactid to the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Dependent jar files not updated properly to the project causing this issue, just check the below option to resolve.
Right Click the project -> Maven -> Update Project -> Force Update of Snapshots/Releases -> Ok

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BbSO.png)